# Recursion Error - Degrees of Separation

Tags: python, database, recursion

I'm trying to find degrees of separation between any two actors in a movie database.
I succeed when I reach my base case, which is 1 degree of separation (i.e. actor is in same movie as another actor) but I use recursion to find all other degrees of separation, and I get:

> ```
> runtime error: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp.
> ```

```
##gets file with movie information
f = open("filename.txt")
actedWith = {}
ActorList = []
movies = {}
actedIn = []
dos = 1

def getDegrees(target, base, dos):
    for actor in actedWith[base]:
        if target == actor:
            print base, "has ", dos, " degree(s) of separation from ", target
            return
    dos = dos+1
    for actor in actedWith[base]:
        getDegrees(target, actor, dos)


for l in f:
    ##strip of whitespace
    l = l.strip()
    ##split by where forward-slashes are
    l = l.split("/")
    ##add the first "word" on the line to the database of movie names
    movies = {l[0] : l[1:]}
    for e in l[1:]:
        if e in actedWith:
            actedWith[e] = actedWith[e]+movies[l[0]]
        else:
            actedWith[e] = movies[l[0]]

base = raw_input("Enter Actor Name (Last, First): ")
target = raw_input("Enter Second Actor Name (Last, First): ")
getDegrees(target, base, dos)
```

Text file I use can be found at http://www.mediafire.com/?qtryvkzmuv5jey3

To test base case, I use: `Bacon, Kevin` and `Pitt, Brad`.

To test others I use `Bacon, Kevin` and `Gamble, Nathan`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions (I haven't looked on the text file, just going on first principles here and a quick read of your code):

1. When you return from getDegrees, you're still going through the rest of the function following the return. You need to return a True (or something) to indicate that the search is over and the entire function call stack should be rolled back. The first return would change to "return True" and the last line would change to "if getDegrees(target, actor, dos): return True".
2. Keep track of which actors have already been searched. If two actors have each acted with each other, or there is a cycle in the relationships, you'll loop back and forth.

This code attempts to fix both the return and graph cycle problems. However, there is still a logic error somewhere; Kevin Bacon and James Belushi (degree of separation of 2) give the following:

> Siravo, Joseph has  179  degree(s) of separation from  Belushi, James

Edit: fixed by adding the "original" parameter.

but the recursion problem is fixed.

```
##gets file with movie information
f = open("filename.txt")
actedWith = {}
ActorList = []
movies = {}
actedIn = []
dos = 1

def getDegrees(original, target, base, dos=0, seen=[]):
    dos = dos+1
    print "----> checking %s against %s" % (target, base)
    for actor in actedWith[base]:
        #print "\t" + actor
        if target == actor:
            print original, "has ", dos, " degree(s) of separation from ", target
            return True
    for actor in actedWith[base]:
        if actor in seen: continue
        seen = seen + [actor]
        if getDegrees(original, target, actor, dos, seen):
            return True
    return False


for l in f:
    ##strip of whitespace
    l = l.strip()
    ##split by where forward-slashes are
    l = l.split("/")
    ##add the first "word" on the line to the database of movie names
    movies = {l[0] : l[1:]}
    for e in l[1:]:
        if e in actedWith:
            actedWith[e] = actedWith[e]+movies[l[0]]
        else:
            actedWith[e] = movies[l[0]]

original = raw_input("Enter Actor Name (Last, First): ")
target = raw_input("Enter Second Actor Name (Last, First): ")
getDegrees(original, target, original)
```

Example:

```
Bacon, Kevin has  65  degree(s) of separation from  Kosaka, Masami
```

Comment: No...recursion problem is still present, unfortunately. I input a different set of actors: Bacon, Kevin and Kosaka, Masami. Same recursion error. 
Error with returning different names is caused by 'print base, "has ", dos, " degree(s) of separation from ", target' By creating a new variable to store the original base, the problem is solved, though the logical error with counting degrees is still present.

Comment: @RMartin Check your implementation, please. I just tested that name and it works fine.

Comment: Sorry about that...Try Johnson, Cherie. 
I just copy/pasted your code to make sure; it seems to search through many of them and then returns runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's some property of `actedWith` I'm not seeing, you have nothing in place to prevent an infinite loop.  For example, one of your recursive calls will be `getDegrees("Gamble, Nathan", "Pitt, Brad", 2)`, then since Kevin Bacon has acted with Brad Pitt, when you go another level deeper you will call `getDegrees("Gamble, Nathan", "Bacon, Kevin", 3)`.  See the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably infinite recursion.  You're searching a tree rooted on target; and some of the paths on that tree is reaching points that are upstream of them.  You need a way to recognise this and stop looking down that path when it occurs.

One way is to keep a list of ancestors on the path.  Something like:

```
def getDegrees(target, base, dos, ancestors):  # Also carry a list of "ancestors"
    for actor in actedWith[base]:
        if target == actor:
            print base, "has ", dos, " degree(s) of separation from ", target
            return
    dos = dos+1
    ancestors = ancestors + [base]  # Must be separate variable binding to avoid mutating the caller's copy
    for actor in actedWith[base]:
        if actor in ancestors: continue  # Check if on path, skip if so
        getDegrees(target, actor, dos, ancestors)

...

getDegrees(target, base, dos, [target])
```

Note that "ancestor" means a point on the path, not a person that an actor might be related to.

This doesn't avoid the case where an actor has `actedWith` themself (hopefully the input file will never contain that), but it could with a small change.

Comment: I tried implementing this...However, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @RMartin This code is incorrect; it does not pass ancestors into the getDegrees recurse, nor does it fix the return issue.

Comment: Ah, true.  Problem is I was too lazy to run it.